# One time paid or open-source Bitcoin exchange

Tags: exchanges, trading, bitcoin-core-development

Which is the best cryptocurrency exchange on the market?
It can be one-time paid or open-source, no PHP projects, no outdated, no decentralised like forkdelta.

I found BlinkTrade, which seems work only with BlinkTrade API. https://blinktrade.com/

Peatio seems very hard to integration and outdated. https://github.com/peatio/peatio

Coinffeine, I am not checked this deeply. http://www.coinffeine.com/

ViaBTC have open the server, but not full code. https://github.com/viabtc/viabtc_exchange_server

Seems there is out some system, which are using many exchanges - like Bittrex, etc. Many seems very similiar.
Can you maybe mention some exchange source, which you think is preatty good.
I can pay for code as well with reasonable price.

Comment: Peatio  Is Good !!! I can help you to run  Bitcoin exchange  with this.

Comment: Sadly I cannot agree with you.

Comment: Okay, but why are you against it?